# Include file not found in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import

I have one project in which I have added many projects to react native use. The folder arrangement is as shown in the figure.

[image: Project is here]

& imported project is here...

[image: REACT project here which files we need to import]

Now I am using

> pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

which will add RNFSManager.h files to project which is showing this error.

[image]

What I tried is: I have tried added header search path like this...

[image]

Comment: Did you already manage to solve this error?